# Listview not scrollable in RecyclerView using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` which contains `ListView` inside. I have to use `ConstraintLayout` since I need to align `TextView` and `ListView` properly for **each row of `RecyclerView`**. But it seems the listview cannot scroll when there's too much content on screen.

*recyclerview_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textColor="#0E1C2B"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerview_list"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Date: "
    android:textColor="#0E1C2B"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.207"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_list"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My own SOLUTION*

Must add `LinearLayout` around ListView element.

> Those lines with stars are which have differences with the original one.

.
*Final recyclerview_layout.xml:*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

---------other code are the same------------

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
    **android:orientation="vertical"**
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.011">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_list"
        **android:layout_width="match_parent"**
        **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="104dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You want to use `RecyclerView` or `ListView`? Here, I have added a `RecyclerView` with a proper constraint. Sometimes adding a wrong constraint can get you a scrolling error.
>
> Let me know if you want another in below design

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="#0E1C2B"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Date: "
        android:textColor="#0E1C2B"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/time"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_list"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I mean... The listview is within the recyclerview. Strcuture is as the last pic in my question. The reason I used like this is that both ListView and Recyclerview items are need to be updated while user has interaction. Now I set both ListView and RecyclerView `layout_height = "wrap_content"` . But it seems listview can only show one item and it's not scrollable. (but there does have a scroll. Strange)